# console output & gui textfield in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, textfield, scenebuilder

I am a new programmer in javafx. I am building a desktop application named as fuzzy calculator. whenever I run this program it opens a user interface but when click on the button(Max-Min) in the interface I found my  output in the console instead of textfield. How can I get my desired output in the textfield I have created??? I have already wasted too many hours searching the solution but none of them is working or clear to me.

I am attaching my code below for your suggestion..

N.B: as my application is in developing mood all button is not working currently, only Max-min button is active.

Main.java

```
 import javafx.scene.Parent;
 import javafx.scene.Scene;
 import javafx.stage.Stage;

 public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Fuzzy Calculator");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Controller.java

```
package sample;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Controller {
@FXML
private Button add;

@FXML
private Button maxmin;

@FXML
private Button maxavg;

@FXML
private Button sub;

@FXML
private TextField display;

@FXML
private Button maxprod;

@FXML
private Button minmax;

@FXML
 void maxmin(ActionEvent event) {

   System.out.println("Array size:");
   Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
   int n=input.nextInt();
   System.out.println("1st input ");
   int a[][]=new int [n][n];
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
       {
           a[i][j]=input.nextInt();
       }
   }
   System.out.println("2nd input ");
   int b[][]=new int [n][n];

   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
       {
           b[i][j]=input.nextInt();
       }
   }
   int [] c=new int [n];
   int [] k=new int [n];
   int t=0;
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       t=0;
       for(int j=0;j<n;j++ )
       {

           if(a[i][j]<b[j][i])
           {
               k[t]=a[i][j];
               t++;
           }
           else
           {
               k[t]=b[j][i];
               t++;
           }
       }
       Arrays.sort(k);
       c[i]=k[n-1];
   }
   System.out.println("the output is :");
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       System.out.print(" "+c[i]);
   }

}
}
```

sample.fxml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
 <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
 <?import java.lang.*?>
 <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
 <?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
 <?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
 <?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
 <?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
<children>
  <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" layoutX="102.0" layoutY="51.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="25.0">
    <items>
      <AnchorPane maxHeight="100.0" prefHeight="80.0">
           <children>
              <TextField fx:id="display" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="42.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="598.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="15.0" />
                 </font>
              </TextField>
           </children>
        </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="230.0" prefWidth="598.0">
           <children>
              <GridPane layoutY="6.0" prefHeight="267.0" prefWidth="598.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                <columnConstraints>
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                </columnConstraints>
                <rowConstraints>
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                </rowConstraints>
                 <children>
                    <Button fx:id="maxmin" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#maxmin" prefHeight="134.0" prefWidth="199.0" text="Max-Min">
                       <font>
                          <Font size="28.0" />
                       </font>
                    </Button>
                    <Button fx:id="maxprod" alignment="CENTER" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="134.0" prefWidth="199.0" text="Max_Product" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
                       <font>
                          <Font size="28.0" />
                       </font>
                    </Button>
                    <Button fx:id="maxavg" alignment="CENTER" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="134.0" prefWidth="199.0" text="Max_Average" GridPane.columnIndex="2">
                       <font>
                          <Font size="27.0" />
                       </font>
                    </Button>
                    <Button fx:id="add" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="134.0" prefWidth="199.0" text="Addition" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                       <font>
                          <Font size="28.0" />
                       </font>
                    </Button>
                    <Button fx:id="sub" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="134.0" prefWidth="199.0" text="Subtraction" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                       <font>
                          <Font size="28.0" />
                       </font>
                    </Button>
                    <Button fx:id="minmax" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="134.0" prefWidth="199.0" text="Min-Max" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                       <font>
                          <Font name="System Bold" size="28.0" />
                       </font>
                    </Button>
                 </children>
              </GridPane>
           </children>
        </AnchorPane>
    </items>
  </SplitPane>
  </children>
 </AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All seems normal with your code, it does what you wrote

```
System.out.println("the output is :");
```

will print into the console, because this is the standard output

You said you want to print into the textfield so just write it :

```
display.setText(display.getText()+"new text, with its value : + 65);
```

---

`setText()` is to decide which text will appear into

`getText()` is to get back the text already into, it allows to do concatenation

Because if you use only `setText();` you'll have something like this :

```
display.setText("log n°1 ...");
```

> log n°1

```
display.setText("log n°2 ...");
```

> log n°2

And you want to add the text and not replace it so :

```
display.setText("log n°1 ...\n");
```

> log n°1

```
display.setText(display.getText() + "log n°2 ...");
```

> log n°1
>
> log n°2

---

But this is updating the UI from a different thread. The UI can only be updated from the UI thread. To achieve this, you've to do like this

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
         display.setText(display.getText() + "log n°2 ...");
});
```

It tells the UI Thread to do the task ;)

Comment: I have tried your approach but this time the whole interface become freeze. and both the console and textfield is blank. I am not getting output anywhere. what should I do?
thank you..

Comment: This is "normal", you are sending a lot of data in the Thread in charge of compute your loop which is bloking the one in charge of the interface

Comment: I am totally bank, what should I do? 
Can you write the necessary changes for me please?

Comment: a minute please, i'm not waiting on my laptop to provide answers ^^ I've edited

Answer (score 0):

Always use `settext` method of Textbox or Label class which you are using for output instead of `System.out.printin()`